# Using DateFormatter on a Unix timestamp

Tags: swift, date, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

I get a crash when running and it points at the `dateFormmater.timezone`. 
The error in the console is:

> Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Optional' (0x1192bf4a8) to 'NSTimeZone' (0x1192c0270).

the value of `rowEvents.date` is `"1480134638.0"`

Im trying to pull out a Unix timestamp from Firebase saved as a string. Convert it to Date and again save it as a string so I can post it on a cell label.

I got this code from StackOverflow. I plugged in my data and everything is all good until I run it. I guess everything is not all good...

```
if let lastUpdated : String = rowEvents.date {

    let epocTime = TimeInterval(lastUpdated)! / 1000 // convert it from milliseconds dividing it by 1000

    let unixTimestamp = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: epocTime) //convert unix timestamp to Date

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone() as TimeZone!
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current // NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat =  "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
    dateFormatter.date(from: String(describing: unixTimestamp))

    let updatedTimeStamp = unixTimestamp
    let cellDate = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: updatedTimeStamp as Date, dateStyle: DateFormatter.Style.full, timeStyle: DateFormatter.Style.medium)

    cell.subtitleLabel.text = cellDate              
}
```

The result came from this code here:

```
let myTimeStamp = self.datePicker?.date.timeIntervalSince1970

let calendarDate = String(describing: myTimeStamp! /** 1000*/)
```

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You can convert `unixTimestamp` to date using `Date(timeIntervalSince1970:)`.

```
let unixTimestamp = 1480134638.0
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: unixTimestamp)
```

If you want to display date in string with specific formate than you can use `DateFormatter` like this way.

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: unixtimeInterval)
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT") //Set timezone that you want
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" //Specify your format that you want
let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

Comment: `TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")` — finally, someone used `TimeZone` constructors instead of `NSTimeZone` ones with casting.

Comment: Thank you so much sir! thhat top one solved it because I didnt care what format. Im sure the bottom code wouldve too if i needed a certain format. I will keep both codes in mind next time I have to do conversions!!!

Comment: @ReyCerio Welcome mate :)

Comment: Can you update this for swift 4.1. There is no method like this  Date(timeIntervalSince1970: unixTimestamp)

Comment: @NiravD did you tell me how can i convert reverse like dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a to timestamp ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya you just need to get the date object using `DateFormatter` method `date(from:)` once you have `Date` object you can easily get timestamp from it

Comment: @Ali let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(timeStamp)). its my code in swift 5. i set timeStamp value earlier

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya let date = Date()
        let timeStamp = date.timeIntervalSince1970 . this code is in swift 5

Answer (score 10):

The problem is the line `dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone() as TimeZone!`.

Simply use `TimeZone` instead of `NSTimeZone` like
`dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current` and your code will work.

*You might also remove your `/ 1000` because `1480134638.0` looks more like seconds than milliseconds (since 1970).*

Comment: Thank you sir! i took out the /1000 because of your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It's getting fine after /1000

Answer (score 7):

Swift 4.1. I created a function. Just pass you timeStamp in function param and function will return data in string data type. You can add more properties to DateFormatter object.

```
func getDateFromTimeStamp(timeStamp : Double) -> String {

        let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timeStamp / 1000)
        
        let dayTimePeriodFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dayTimePeriodFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM YY, hh:mm a"
     // UnComment below to get only time
    //  dayTimePeriodFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"  

        let dateString = dayTimePeriodFormatter.string(from: date as Date)
        return dateString
    }
```

Comment: it is giving error on second last line "Cannot convert value of type 'NSDate' to type 'Date' in coercion"

Answer (score 2):

Using playground all I did was this.

```
let epochTime = 1547855446
let newTime = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(epochTime))
print(newTime)
```

Returns this - 2019-01-18 23:50:46 +0000

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Double{ 
 func convertDate(formate: String) -> String { 
  let date = (timeIntervalSince1970: self)
  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
  dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "(your localization language)" ) as Locale //localization language
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = formate //Specify your format that you want let 
  strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
  return strDate
 }
}

//usage
let timeStamp:Double = Double(1595407043)
print(timeStamp.convertDate(formate: "EEEE dd/MM/YYY"))
```

Comment: Please may you add an explaination to your answer?

Answer (score -2):

This solution is valid for swift 3 -> 4.2 :

you can add an extension on the Double that returns the date formatted:

```
extension Double {


    // returns the date formatted.    
    var dateFormatted : String? {
        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: self)
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none //Set time style
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short //Set date style
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
     }

    // returns the date formatted according to the format string provided. 
    func dateFormatted(withFormat format : String) -> String{
         let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: self)
         let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
         dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
         return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }

}
```

example on the above :

```
let timeStamp = 82749029.0
print(timeStamp. dateFormatted)
//output
//12/11/1994



let timeStamp = 82749029.0
print(timeStamp. dateFormatted(withFormat : "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"))
//output
//12-11-1994 13:04
```