# How to get JSON data and show it on a table view cell

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

I passed a JSON data to this table view controller. How to get the JSON data and show it on a table view cell?

When I print `passedData` I receive the following output:

```
["jobs": <__NSArrayM 0x17005d9d0>
({
    jobDate = "2017-08-31";
    jobEndTime = 1504144800;
    jobID = 87;
    jobTime = 1504137600;
},
{
    jobDate = "2017-08-31";
    jobEndTime = 1504173600;
    jobID = 89;
    jobTime = 1504170000;
}), 
"result": success, 
"message": Retrieve Sucessfully]
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
var passedData: [String: Any]!

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let jobs = passedData["jobs"] as? [[String:Any]] else {return 0}
    return jobs.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath  indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "jobCell", for: indexPath)

    // jobs[indexPath.row] display jobTime 

    return cell       
 }
```

Comment: What do you actually want to display on the cell? If you want to display more than one piece of information, you will most probably need to subclass `UITableViewCell` and create your own class for storing the job data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of giving you a reply on the subject I would try to help understanding the domain you are working with.

The JSON response you are retrieving contains an array (`jobs`) where each element is an object. In fact, the JSON syntax states that:

> In JSON, values must be one of the following data types:
>
> - a string
> - a number
> - an object (JSON object)
> - an array
> - a boolean
> - null

If you are using `JSONSerialization` class, then you will have a dictionary that will contain an array of dictionaries.

A simple snippet like this will give you that array

```
if let jsonArray = jsonDict["jobs"] as? [[String: Any]] {
    print(jsonArray)
}
```

Now, in order to access elements of that array you can do like the following:

```
let jsonArrayDict = jsonArray[0]
print(jsonArrayDict["jobTime"] ?? 0)
```

Obviously the code here is not production ready since you need to pay attention to possible crashes of your app.

What I really suggest is to work with a model that can be passed to your table view cell. This approach has these benefits:

- avoid using optionals
- document your code
- unit test your code
- etc.

Here an example on how to convert your JSON object into a specific model. Run it in a playground and practice.

```
struct Job {
    let jobDate: String
    let jobEndTime: Int
    let jobID: Int
    let jobTime: Int
}

extension Job {
    init?(dict: [String: Any]) {
        guard let jobDate = dict["jobDate"] as? String,
            let jobEndTime = dict["jobEndTime"] as? Int,
            let jobID = dict["jobID"] as? Int,
            let jobTime = dict["jobTime"] as? Int else {
                return nil
        }
        self.jobDate = jobDate
        self.jobEndTime = jobEndTime
        self.jobID = jobID
        self.jobTime = jobTime
    }
}

extension Job: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "Job: \(jobDate) \(jobEndTime) \(jobID) \(jobTime)"
    }
}

let jsonString = """
    {
        "jobs": [
            {
                "jobDate": "2017-08-31",
                "jobEndTime": 1504144800,
                "jobID": 87,
                "jobTime": 1504137600
            },
            {
            "jobDate2": "2017-08-31",
            "jobEndTime": 1504144800,
            "jobID": 87,
            "jobTime": 1504137600
            }
        ],
        "result": "success",
        "message": "Retrieve Sucessfully"
    }
"""

if let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8), let jsonObject = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []),
    let jsonDict = jsonObject as? [String: Any],
    let jsonArray = jsonDict["jobs"] as? [[String: Any]] {
    let jobs = jsonArray.flatMap { Job(dict: $0) }
    print(jobs)
} else {
    print("No Results")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you understand the steps needed to parse and use the JSON data that you have. You will likely need to create a custom UITableViewCell which is beyond the scope of this answer. There are plenty of resources online which will explain this part of the process.

You will also need to convert your timestamps to dates, there are alot of answers on StackOverflow that can help with this. Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40648284/converting-a-unix-timestamp-into-date-as-string-swift)

**Mapping JSON Data**

```
let passedJsonStr = "{\"jobs\":[{\"jobDate\":\"2017-08-31\",\"jobEndTime\":1504144800,\"jobID\":87,\"jobTime\":1504137600},{\"jobDate\":\"2017-08-31\",\"jobEndTime\":1504173600,\"jobID\":89,\"jobTime\":1504170000}],\"result\":\"success\",\"message\":\"Retrieve Sucessfully\"}"

struct Job {
    var jobDate: String
    var jobEndTime: Int
    var jobID: Int
    var jobTime: Int

    init(dict: [String:AnyObject]) {
        // unwrap these safely, I'm just giving an example
        self.jobDate = dict["jobDate"] as! String
        self.jobEndTime = dict["jobEndTime"] as! Int
        self.jobID = dict["jobID"] as! Int
        self.jobTime = dict["jobTime"] as! Int
    }
}

var jobs = [Job]()

if let data = passedJsonStr.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {

    if let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject] {

        if let jsonData = jsonObject["jobs"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
            jobs = jsonData.map { Job(dict: $0) }
        }

        print(jobs)
    }
}
```

**Displaying in UITableView**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath  indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "jobCell", for: indexPath)

    let job = self.jobs[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel.text = job.jobDate

    return cell       
 }
```

Comment: Updated with working example from playground. Previous code was done on phone and was meant as a guide. Thanks

Comment: use `let` instead of `var` in your structure. In addition, I would use an `init?` initializer in order to skip objects that are not correct.