# Getting date and time from unix timestamp

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, unix-timestamp

I am trying to get current date and time from a unix time stamp but it keeps giving me the wrong date  this is the code i am currenty

```
 func getDateFromStamp(timeInterval:Int) -> String{
     let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(timeInterval))
     let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMM d, h:mm a"
     let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date)
   return dateString
}
```

Comment: what's wrong about the date? the format? the timezone?

Comment: Please add the Unix timestamp that you are using.

Comment: Please provide input time interval and output date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a Unix timestamp into Date as String? Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40648284/converting-a-unix-timestamp-into-date-as-string-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually unix timestamps are in milliseconds, but Date uses seconds. You might need to divide your timestamp by 1000.

Comment: *"Usually unix timestamps are in milliseconds"* – do you have any reference for that claim? The [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) that I know is the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970, GMT.

Comment: @MartinR I don't really have a specific reference but it's my experience that is talking. Often servers use milliseconds for timestamp. For example when you ask a timestamp in java it's in milliseconds ...

Answer (score 0):

Possible errors:

I try to use milliseconds instead of seconds. `timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval` uses seconds. Divide `timeInterval` by 1000 beforehand.

Or you have not setup TimeZone.

Don't forget to use `Date()` instead of `NSDate()`

It depends on your results and input parameters.

**EDIT**

To change time zone use this code:
 `dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+01:00")`

Comment: I think TimeZone is causing this...how can i set timezone?

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 4:**

**Step:-1** Convert to Date:

```
    let timestamp = "Your TimeStamp here"

    var dateFromTimeStamp = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp as! TimeInterval / 1000)
```

**Step:-2** Convert to appropriate time zone:

```
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter();

    let dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"; //Any TimeFormat you want
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat;
    let formattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: dateFromTimeStamp);

    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current;
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT"); //Pass Appropriate time zone here.

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat as String;
    let sourceDate = dateFormatter.date(from: formattedDate as String);
    print(sourceDate)
```

Hope so this helps You.