# iOS Core Motion how to convert timestamp to Date?

Tags: ios, timestamp, nsdate, core-motion

I'm examining CMRecordedAccelerometerData and it has a timestamp, defined as:

> The timestamp is the amount of time in seconds since the device
>   booted.

**How do I convert timestamp from device last boot to NSDate?**

For example, the system provides a CMRecordedAccelerometerData object with a timestamp value of: 1030958.895134

If I use any of the available reference frames (1970, reference date), I will get a wrong date, not in 2019. I want the real date when the event was recorded.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using DateFormatter on a Unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40648284/using-dateformatter-on-a-unix-timestamp)

Comment: simply `let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeStampHere)` ?

Comment: Please read the question again, the system returns an arbitrary number of seconds since last boot. If I use your solution, I will get a date in the 1970, not in 2019. I want the real date when the event was recorded

Comment: @AlexStone My answer should get you the date of the timestamp. Did it not work for you?

Comment: @akaur I still don't know how to get the timestamp of the last boot, so the answer does not work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer comes a bit late I guess, but, first, you can get the boot time by subtracting the uptime `ProcessInfo.processInfo.systemUptime` from now, but otherwise from iOS 9+ `ProcessInfo.processInfo.systemUptime` has the date property `startDate`, which should be what you were after in the first place.

Answer (score -3):

The timestamp is a TimeInterval, a typealias for Double that represents duration as a number of seconds. So you can convert TimeInterval to a Date by using NSDate's `(timeIntervalSince1970:)`.

```
let myTimeInterval:TimeInterval = 1574660642
let dateNow = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: myTimeInterval)  //will print "Nov 24, 2019 at 9:44 PM"
```

If you need to the date relative to the current date with the TimeInterval, you can use `(timeInterval:since:)`.

```
var date = Date()
let timestampOfLastBoot: TimeInterval = 1572628813
let currentTimestamp: TimeInterval = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
let dateOfTimeStamp = Date(timeInterval: timestampOfLastBoot-currentTimestamp, since: date)    //will print "Nov 1, 2019 at 10:20 AM"
```