# get sunrise ans sunset time

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am trying to get sunrise and sunset and i am using Open weather API to fetch the latitude and the longitude. is there a way to get the sunrise & the sunset time of any city using the latitude and the longitude?

```
extension WeatherViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.last {
        let lat = location.coordinate.latitude
        let lon = location.coordinate.longitude
        weatherManager.fetchWeather(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print(error)
}
```

}

**my Weather Manager**

```
   var delegate: weatherManagerDelegate?

func fetchWeather(cityName: String){
    let urlString = "\(weatherURL)&q=\(cityName)"
    performRequest(with: urlString)
}

func fetchWeather(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees){
    let urlString = "\(weatherURL)&lat=\(latitude)&lon=\(longitude)"
    performRequest(with: urlString)
}
```

Comment: Explain what part of the code you have an issue with or if you are asking about an api or other source for getting the coordinates of a city then that kind of question is considered off-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40648371/1702413

Answer (score 0):

It's on their website and is probably already included in your data if your requests are successful. It's in the `sys` dictionary in the following response. It seems like this is the response type for the APIs you are using.

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": -122.08,
    "lat": 37.39
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "clear sky",
      "icon": "01d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 282.55,
    "feels_like": 281.86,
    "temp_min": 280.37,
    "temp_max": 284.26,
    "pressure": 1023,
    "humidity": 100
  },
  "visibility": 16093,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 1.5,
    "deg": 350
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 1
  },
  "dt": 1560350645,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 5122,
    "message": 0.0139,
    "country": "US",
    "sunrise": 1560343627,
    "sunset": 1560396563
  },
  "timezone": -25200,
  "id": 420006353,
  "name": "Mountain View",
  "cod": 200
}
```

Comment: i am getting the output as SUNRISE = 1585317686 and SUNSET as
1585362476 and i want 24hrs or 12hrs format

Comment: Posted a new answer to help you with this 

Comment: @UpdyhakimBiin These are unix time stamps and you need to format them by code to achieve the desired output. Check the link by Tony directly under your question. If you follow that you should be able to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

Find Out  answer:

For json I used SwiftyJson Library.......

```
            let sunriseTime = myResult["sys"]["sunrise"].doubleValue
            
            let sunriseDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970:  sunriseTime)
             let formatter = DateFormatter()
             formatter.dateStyle = .none
             formatter.timeStyle = .medium

             let formattedTime = formatter.string(from: sunriseDate)
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 self.lblwindspeed.text = "Sunrise: \(formattedTime)"
             }
```

//output:Sunrise: 5:11:03 AM
[image]