# How do I create a (collection?)view like the example I provided

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a view for some appointments. The image I provided is of the app we use right now. It accesses the same API as I am, so we get back the exact same information.

[image: The view]

What I'm exactly trying to recreate here is the view where you can see the appointments and I would like to know how they achieved the view of each day like this.
What I'm getting back from the API (per appointment):

```
    "id":51562,
    "appointmentInstance":21412,
    "start":42364236, //unix
    "end":436234523, //unix
    "startTimeSlot": 1, //can be nil
    "endTimeSlot": 1,
    "subjects":["ne"],
    "teachers":["KRO"],
    "groups":["v1a"],
    "groupsInDepartments":[143],
    "locations":["M92"],
    "locationsOfBranch:[35],
    "type":"lesson",
    "remark":"Take care to bring your books",
    "valid":true,
    "cancelled":false,
    "modified":true,
    "moved":false,
    "new":false,
    "changeDescription":"The location has been changed from M13 to M92",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple libraries for calendar e.g. [JTAppleCalendar](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar) and some in [awesome-ios](https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios#calendar) list.

If you would like to make it from scratch you can do it programmatically the following way:

1. Create UIScrollView
2. Add a grid inside it: lines would be UIView's with width/height of 1
3. Add UILabel's with hours inside it
4. Add each appointment as UIView with UILabel inside it

Comment: How would I place my appointments on the grid if I know the unix time? For example if I have an appointment at 7:00, how would I put my appointment at 7:00 that day on the grid at the right position?

Comment: @kai-353 See first answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40648284/using-dateformatter-on-a-unix-timestamp

Comment: Can you help me out here? I want paging enabled only when scrolling horizontally, but have paging disabled for scrolling vertically (aka just normal scrolling)

Comment: @kai-353 I guess you'll need to add gesture recognizer there